# Chrome ignoring seek and downloads everything in between start and seek value

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I have an audio stream that sends 1 mb of audio data trough Partial-content 206 and everything works, but when I open up a 120 minute (110mb) file and seek almost at the end of song chrome send a request for every byte in song, i.e. instead of just sending a request for that particular place in time it sends for everything between starting point end selected endpoint.

Is this default chrome behavior?

Here is an image of requests that chrome sends.

[image]

Comment: What kind of audio file?  Not all formats are directly seekable.

Comment: @Brad this is mp3 file. And it seems that chrome always downloads everything in-between before it can play anything else.

Comment: MP3 files are not seekable.  The player doesn't know at what offset a particular time will be without downloading the data.  Some players can attempt to needle-drop into a stream, but it isn't accurate and it seems that Chrome's implementation isn't doing that.

Comment: @Brad so basically I'm left with creating my own player that will put chunks of data together received from server and then playback it. Is this something that YouTube practices with their video playback?

Comment: If you're hosting your own files, you can add offsets externally.  Or, you can use a container format that is seekable.  This is regularly done.  What YouTube does is completely irrelevant, since they are using seekable containers.

Comment: @Brad I am hosting my own files, could you give a reference where should I learn more about adding offsets externally and by seekable containers you mean e.g. `.ogg` file format right?

Comment: Ogg cannot contain MP3.  Sorry, I haven't looked into Chrome's seek behavior lately and cannot provide a specific recommendation.  Older versions of Chrome would needle-drop MP3s just fine.